# Is there any way to make "nopagebreak" work before "paracol"

Tags: paracol

I need to build the following structure:

**Title**

--------------------- [`paracol` starts]

contents inside `paracol`

--------------------- [`paracol` ends]

But when the title is at the end of a page, I want to apply `\nopagebreak` to the title in order not to leave the title alone.

However, `\nopagebreak` does not work before `paracol`.
Is there an alternative to make it work?

The following is the actual code and its output.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{18cm}
Title above paracol\nopagebreak[4]
\begin{paracol}{2}
\rule{\textheight}{1pt}

contents in paracol
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot suppress a pagebreak at a `\par` (automatic).  I tried removing the effects of `\topskip`, but the first line overlapped the title.  It seems that paracol just really doesn't like 1 line columns.  So I recommend using `\needspace` to move the title instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{needspace}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{18cm}
\needspace{3\baselineskip}
Title above paracol
\begin{paracol}{2}
\noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{\ht\strutbox}\par

contents in paracol\par
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```